# App rejected saying, your app contains unauthorized use of copyrighted content

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Я разработал музыкальный продукт, используя API для онлайн-музыки. Мое приложение содержит только одну ссылку этого API. после загрузки в Google Play я получил отказ, говоря, что ваше приложение содержит несанкционированное использование контента, защищенного авторским правом. Я обращаюсь, чтобы узнать точную проблему, и они отвечают мне, говоря это___

**Например, ваше приложение в настоящее время содержит

```
Музыка без предоставления юридического подтверждения разрешения. Чтобы продолжить рассмотрение, приложите к этому письму подтверждение.**
```

Описание моего приложения содержит несколько известных музыкальных названий. Например, «Позвольте мне любить вас», «Кесария», «Одинокий», «Сайянн джи» и т. Д. И другие музыкальные названия, а также описание моего приложения содержит имя известного исполнителя.
[image: Email]

my app screenshot...

[image: home]
[image: 2nd]
[image: 3rd]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с каким музыкальным контентом у меня может быть проблема? Я не могу понять, потому что я не использовал музыку в своем приложении. Я использую только ссылку API. пожалуйста помогите мне...

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пожалуйста переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык, или задайте его на англоязычной версии сайта - https://stackoverflow.com/. Please translate your question on Russian or ask it on the English speaking website version - https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: так а апи то чье? музыку вы где берёте?

Comment: Есть ли ошибка в использовании API в приложении?

Comment: Вам может помочь только письменное разрешение правообладателя музыки на её использование. Если его нельзя достать - то приложение вы восстановить не сможете. Если будете пытаться - вам акк забанят.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я не использовал музыку в своем коде приложения.
Я использую только ссылку API.
Считаете ли вы проблемой использовать название музыки в описании моего приложения?
Должен ли я удалить все имя из описания?

Comment: Названия да, нужно удалить. Однако то, что вы будете использовать API может всё равно привести к бану. Я где-то видел случай приложения, которое интернет радио по API юзало и приложение забанили по обращению радио. Но там человек смог за пару тысяч (вроде) долларов с ними договориться.